# Select query with a condition in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables Table-A and Table-B.

Table-A contains

```
id           
1
2
3
4
```

Table-B contains

```
id    tno  data
1      1    regec
1      2    marsec
1      0    lorem
2      1    ipsum
2      0    doller
3      2    sit
3      0    amet
3      1    lipsum
```

In these tables the `id` column is the primary key. I want to get all id's from Table-A, which don't have a corresponding row in Table-B with `tno` as '2'.

My result set looks like this

```
id
2
4
```

Comment: Please post your attempt...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
    SELECT b.id
    FROM tableB b
    WHERE b.tno = 2
)
```

[SQLFIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ae9e/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tableB WHERE tno=2)
```

Comment: After replacing `Table-A` to `TableA` this does not compile with error: `Incorrect syntax near 'EXIST'.: SELECT id FROM TableA WHERE id NOT EXIST(SELECT id FROM TableB WHERE tno=2) `

Comment: I checked again and according to Microsoft it should work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: You checked? Really? How exactly? Who cares what Microsoft says if it does not even compile! This is your example in [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ae9e/21)

Comment: I didn't know he is working with SQLfiddle server. I thought it was sql server 2008. sorry.

Comment: rest assured, this SQLfiddle **is** SQL Server 2008

Comment: The syntax problem was EXIST instead of EXISTS (the last S was missing). anyway I corrected my answer to the IN solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id FROM [Table-A] where Id not in(SELECT id FROM [Table-B] WHERE tno=2)
```

Comment: Nice copy-paste from another answer, it even includes invalid syntax.

Comment: @mvp: why did you comment like that?

Comment: Because you did not bother to try it. `SELECT id FROM Table-A` could not be correct SQL, ever. `SELECT id FROM TableA` - maybe.

Comment: @mvp: I got two tables Table-A and Table-B. He has asked question like this so I just wrote Table-A and Table-B.

Comment: but it does not mean that you can write invalid SQL. And in this case, it did look like 98% copy paste from another answer.